# MongoDBCompas import large JSON file

Tags: mongodb, mongoimport

I have problem with importing large JSON file (it's not JSON Array) which is backup of client database(neither BSON file). I tried both ways of import: from MongoDBCompas GUI and from mongoimport tool. Both import run successfully without errors but file has 10 GB in my computer but after import in server show just 1.91 GB storage size.

My question is if it's some restriction for free version which limits size of import? And if is some way to ensure that whole file was imported?

Comment: The import should show the number of imported documents. Verify this.

Comment: JSON is not a very space-efficient storage method, and the server will use compression when storing the documents.  Actually check to see if any data is missing.